# Is a bindable functor a useful abstraction for more type safe DSLs?

Tags: haskell, monads, dsl

## Motivation

I'm currently working on a little hobby project to try and implement something like [TaskJuggler](http://taskjuggler.org/) in Haskell, mostly as an experiment to play with writing domain specific languages.

My current goal is to have a small DSL for building up the description of a `Project`, along with it's associated `Task`s. There is no hierarchy yet, though that'll be my next extension. Currently, I have the following data types:

```
data Project = Project { projectName :: Text
                       , projectStart :: Day
                       , projectEnd :: Day
                       , projectMaxHoursPerDay :: Int
                       , projectTasks :: [Task]
                       }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data Task = Task { taskName :: Text }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Nothing too crazy there, I'm sure you will agree.

Now I want to create a DSL to build up projects/tasks. I can use `Writer [Task]` monad to build up tasks, but this won't scale well. We might be able to do the following now:

```
project "LambdaBook" startDate endDate $ do
  task "Web site"
  task "Marketing"
```

Where `project :: Text -> Date -> Date -> Writer [Task] a`, which runs the `Writer` to get a list of tasks, and choses a default value such as 8 for `projectMaxHoursPerDay`.

But I will later want to be able to do something like:

```
project "LambdaBook" $ do
  maxHoursPerDay 4
  task "Web site"
  task "Marketing"
```

So I'm using `maxHoursPerDay` to specify a (future) property about a `Project`. I can no longer use a `Writer` for this, because `[Task]` isn't able to capture everything I need.

I see two possibilities for solving this problem:

### Separate "optional" properties into their own monoid

I could split `Project` into:

```
data Project = Project { projectName, projectStart, projectEnd, projectProperties }
data ProjectProperties = ProjectProperties { projectMaxHoursPerDay :: Maybe Int
                                           , projectTasks :: [Task]
                                           }
```

Now I can have an instance `Monoid ProjectProperties`. When I run `Writer ProjectProperties` I can do all the defaulting I need to build a `Project`. I suppose there's no reason that `Project` needs to embed `ProjectProperties` - it could even have the same definition as above.

### Use the bindable functor `Semigroup m => Writer m`

While `Project` isn't a `Monoid`, it can certainly be made into a `Semigroup`. Name/start/end are `First`, `maxHoursPerDay` is `Last`, and `projectTasks` is `[Task]`. We can't have a `Writer` monad over a `Semigroup`, but we can have a `Writer` bindable functor.

## The Actual Question

With the first solution - a dedicated 'properties' `Monoid` - we can use the full power of a monad, at a choice of costs. I could duplicate the overridable properties in `Project` and `ProjectProperties`, where the latter wraps each property in an appropriate monoid. Or I could just write the monoid once and embed it inside the `Project` - though I give up type safety (`maxHoursPerDay` *must* be `Just` when I actually produce the project plan!).

A bindable functor removes both the code duplication and retains type safety, but at the immediate cost of giving up syntax sugar, and the potentially longer term cost of being a pain to work with (due to lack of `return`/`pure`).

I have examples of both approaches at http://hpaste.org/82024 (for bindable functors), and http://hpaste.org/82025 (for the monad approach). These examples go a little beyond what's in this SO post (which was big enough already), and has `Resource` along with `Task`. Hopefully this will indicate why I need to go as far `Bind` (or `Monad`) in the DSL.

I'm excited to have even found an applicable use for bindable functors, so I'm happy to hear any thoughts or experience you might have.

Comment: `maxHoursPerDay 4` is really a transformer (Project -> Project), making it a command in your monadic DSL means you can easily encode  junk like `do { maxHoursPerDay 4;` `maxHoursPerDay 2;` `task "my-task" }` - maybe it should be encoded more along the lines of the Writer monad's `pass` rather than `tell`.

Comment: @stephentetley that is true, I hadn't considered that. Having `Last` on it does at least mean that has some sort of semantic meaning. One thing I do ultimately want is to be able to set a property on some parent `Task`/`Project` and have it be inherited by children, but still, having it as a command in the monad/whatever is not essential for that.

Answer (score 4):

```
data Project maxHours = Project {tasks :: [Task], maxHourLimit :: maxHours}

defProject = Project [] ()

setMaxHours :: Project () -> Project Double
setMaxHours = ...

addTask :: Project a -> Project a

type CompleteProject = Project Double...

runProject :: CompleteProject -> ...

storeProject :: CompleteProject -> ...
```

You need function composition now, instead of actions in a writer, but this pattern lets you start with a partially populated record, and set those things that need to be set once and only once with plenty of type safety. It even lets you impose constraints on the relationship between various set and unset values in the final result.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not so convinced on this - it feels it doesn't scale particularly well in the area of the expression problem. Also, what is a `Project Char`? We probably only get a decent embedding here if we limit maxHours to be a specific kind, some sort of "option" kind.

Comment: I don' follow the "area of the expression problem"? A `Project Char` is something we can't run, and so irrelevant :-) That said, sure, kinds could help possibly too, but I don't see much extra safety coming from them.

Comment: Sure we don't run a `Project Char`, but I'd rather not be able to construct things that are well outside the domain of projects. I mention the expression problem just because I haven't found a nice solution that doesn't make it a pain to add new properties. And while we don't run `Project Char`, we certainly do interpret `Projects' - if it's to schedule them, find a critical path, or other such things.

Comment: Edited to show how to use a type alias in this style to restrict _all_ uses of Project to completed ones. Adding a new property in this style, just like to a new record normally, should be an extremely local change.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting solution that was proposed on Google+ was to use a normal `Writer` monad, but using the `Endo Project` monoid. Along with `lens`, this yields a very nice DSL:

```
data Project = Project { _projectName :: String
                       , _projectStart :: Day
                       , _projectEnd :: Day
                       , _projectTasks :: [Task]
                       }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

makeLenses ''Project
```

Along with the operation

```
task :: String -> ProjectBuilder Task
task name = t <$ mapProject (projectTasks <>~ [t])
  where t = Task name []
```

Which can be used with the original DSL. This is probably the best solution for what I want (though maybe using a monad is just too much of an abuse of syntax anyway).

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a non-answer, but I feel it should be said.

Isn't record syntax good enough? Do you really need a DSL for marginally improved syntax?

```
defaultProject
  { projectName = "Lambdabook"
  , projectStart = startDate
  , projectEnd = endDate
  , tasks =
    [ Task "Web site"
    , Task "marketing"
    ]
  }
```

Tangentially, a Racketeer once told me that Haskell only has one macro: `do` syntax. So Haskellers shoehorn everything into monads whenever they want to manipulate syntax.